# iOS realm multiple filter based on if else statements

Tags: ios, swift, filtering, realm

Is it possible to have multiple filters which are used based on the outcome of them?

I want to filter a list of university courses based on their name and check if the list of filtered courses is > 0. If not, i automatically get them all.

This is what im doing right now, giving the user a button to show all if the view is empty:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if let courseName = GetCourseName(){
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains %@", courseName)
            courses = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).filter(predicate).sorted("name")
            token = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).filter(predicate).addNotificationBlock({ changes in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show all", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(showAll(_:)))]

        }else{
            courses = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).sorted("name")
            token = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).addNotificationBlock({ changes in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }

func showAll(sender:AnyObject)
    {
        courses = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).sorted("name")
        token = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).addNotificationBlock({ changes in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.removeAll()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something like this should work. Basically, if there is a course name, set courses to the filtered results. Then, if courses is nil or empty, set it to show all.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let courseName = GetCourseName(){
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains %@", courseName)
        courses = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).filter(predicate).sorted("name")
    }

    if course == nil || course.isEmpty {
        courses = try! RealmManager.realm().objects(Course.self).sorted("name")
    }

    token = courses.addNotificationBlock({ changes in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: I used your solution. But i put everything in the token block. Because im fetching the data new every time when the user navigates to the view. course == nil is than always true in the viewDidLoad method